# Transitive group actions and transitive subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

I am given the following problem:

> Show that $S_6$ has a subgroup $H$, which is isomorphic to $S_5$ and acts transitively on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Before this I proved that $S_5$ has six $5$-sylow groups. Working on this question I soon got pretty lost, so I looked up the solution. Trying to understand it, I came up with three questions.

Here is the part of the solution I struggle with:

*$S_5$ acts transitively on the six $5$-Sylow groups. This gives a homomorphism $\sigma: S_5 \to S_6$. Therefore $H:= \sigma(S_5)$ is transitive. Since $H \cong S_5/K$, where $K$ denotes the kernel of $\sigma$, is transitive of order $6$ we have $|S_5/K| \geq 6$. (The solution than continues to show that $K$ is trivial.)*

I am not familiar with the concept of transitive groups. I looked it up and found the following definition of transitive groups: "Let $M$ be a set and $G:=S_{|M|}$ the permutation group of $M$. A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called transitive if for each $x,y \in M$ there is a $\sigma \in H$ such that $\sigma(x) = y$." So far, so good.

> Regarding the solution above, I struggle to understand three points:
>
> 1. Why is $H:= \sigma(S_5)$ transitive?
> 2. Why is $H$ transitive of order $6$?
> 3. Why does this mean that $|S_5/K| \color{red}{\geq} 6$?

Comment: Part 1 follows from Sylow's Theorem: any two Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ are conjugate in $G$. As for 2, I think you might have misquoted the proof. We don't know that $H$ has order exactly 6, but since it is acting transitively on 6 points, it has order divisible by 6. The answer to 3 is that it follows from the First Isomorphism Theorem, because $S_5/K \cong H$.

Comment: For (2) you mean degree 6, not order 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. $H = \sigma(S_5)$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_6$ precisely because the action of $S_5$ on the $5$-sylow subgroups is transitive.

To say more, we know that $S_5$ acts on a set of size $6$, namely the $5$-sylow subgroups, by conjugation. Moreover, since we know any two $5$-sylow subgroups are conjugate, this action carries any subgroup to any other subgroup (that is, the action is transitive). But what *is* an action on a set of size $6$? It's exactly a homomorphism $\sigma : S_5 \to S_6$. If we look at $H$, the image of $\sigma$, it encodes the same action (modulo any two elements that act the same way). Now since $S_5$ was acting transitively on those $6$ elements, we see that $H$ acts transitively too, so it's a transitive subgroup of $S_6$.

2. I'm not sure what "$H$ is transitive of order $6$" even means here... I imagine it means it's acting transitively on a set of size $6$, because
3. If $H = S_5 / K$ is acting transitively on a set of size $6$, then it has to have at least $6$ elements! Indeed, we must have $6 \ \big | \ |H|$, basically because of the [orbit stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem) (since the action has one orbit).

For more information about all this, you might be interested in Keith Conrad's notes on transitive group actions, which you can find [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/transitive.pdf).

---

I hope this helps ^_^